# GET requests in Facebook open graph meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am pretty new to Open Graph Actions. So, unable to fix this small issue.

I am developing a canvas application where I used in-built read-article meta tags

```
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP ID" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="article" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/article?postid=1" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Underwater Shades" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Z-yBlXMMYWo/UBUYe-Lc46I/AAAAAAAAAxc/VO9XB7Ls-sY/s640/Under+water.JPG" />
```

If you have noticed, I used a GET request and Facebook app URL in `og:url`. (I want uses to get directed to app when they click links)

Now, I just added "Like" social plugin initially to check whether everything is working fine! and surprisingly its not working.

This is what the debugger is showing:

```
Response Code:  401

Tiny og:image:  All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification.

# Raw OG Document Information

Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="365662310180674" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url" content="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/article?postid=1" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Surya Test App" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/y_/r/9myDd8iyu0B.gif" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="Surya Test App" />
```

Where is the problem and how should I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake:

> If you have noticed, I used a GET request and Facebook app URL in
>   og:url. (I want uses to get directed to app when they click links)

If **og:url** is anything other than the current page it is telling Facebook to "ignore these meta tags and go get the ones at this location instead."

However, this is not where your current issue lies.

**Your re-direct is what is causing this problem.**

Facebook can detect redirection and will attempt to grab those open graph meta tags instead. This is exactly what is happening with your described issue.

**How to fix it:**

Change the URL in your Like Button code to this:

```
 http://o-e.us/e.php?o=53fa
```

**For Example**, if you are using the XFBML Like button code, it should look like this:

```
<fb:like href="http://o-e.us/e.php?o=53fa" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

**I got this using:**

[Facebook/Open Graph Like Button Generator](http://o-e.us/fb/lbg)

Using the info from above, I entered:

- **Title**: Underwater Shades
- **Image URL**: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Z-yBlXMMYWo/UBUYe-Lc46I/AAAAAAAAAxc/VO9XB7Ls-sY/s640/Under+water.jpg
- **Description**: View Underwater Shades on Surya Test App
- **Redirect URL**: http://apps.facebook.com/surya-dev-app/post?feed_link=http://withmycam.blogspot.com/2012/07/underwater-shades.html

I tested it and it's working for me so hopefully it helps you out. You can change the info I entered and generate a new URL if what I entered doesn't work for you. Good Luck!

Comment: actually I am not using multiple like buttons on the page. so why should I use a redirect url

Comment: I am just saying that,. my graph meta tags are not working properly

Comment: Your URL is: http://apps.facebook.com/surya-dev-app/article?postid=1. FB is attempting to grab meta tags from: http://apps.facebook.com/surya-dev-app/post?feed_link=http://withmycam.blogspot.com/2012/07/underwater-shades.html the tags cant be grabbed from your iframed site while FB is the parent window (they are grabbed from APP settings info/pics instead). You can change the link to: http://withmycam.blogspot.com/2012/07/underwater-shades.html to grab the meta tags directly from that page but users who click the wall 'like' post wont be sent to the FB app. That's why I suggested my tool.

Comment: there has been a small mistake when I was writing the question. og:url in the above two code blogs have been changed now. please take a look.

Comment: I wonder if you could tell me how Washington Post Social Reader redirects their users to their app from graph actions!!

Comment: Try going to https://apps.facebook.com/surya-dev-app/article?postid=1 right click on your page within the facebook frame to "view frame source" vs. view page source. Do you see open graph tags anywhere? I don't. Here is Washington Post Like button code data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Washington-Post-Social-Reader/267401179951379" data-layout="button_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false" as you can see all of their 'Like' buttons (inside of their app) link to their facebook page and not to the specific article you are viewing. There's a tricky way to achieve what you want but

Comment: that requires more than just a 'Like' button and meta tag code.

Answer (score 0):

Um... it says so in the error message.  The image you provided in your meta tags is 75x75px.  You'll need to put a larger image - one with at least 200x200px dimentions.

> All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions...

Your iamge - 75x75px

[image]
<sub>(source: [facebook.com](https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/y_/r/9myDd8iyu0B.gif))</sub>

Image from example - 390x366px

[image]

Comment: actually, I initially used a 650 x 650 image but I was showing the same error.

Comment: @den - perhaps you referenced more than one image and one of them was smaller.

Comment: Thats not possible. The above og meta tags are all I got. I even changed the og:url to the actual one.

Comment: your `og:url` is pointing to `apps.facebook.com`.  Do you maybe want to point it directly to the URL?

Comment: I don't mind if the URL would direct user to my app and not to my website